# Loading failed inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js in angular after building angular app

Tags: angular

Create Angular app -> ng new command
than build it with the help of -> ng build --prod --aot

after put all the files of dist folder into production server error ocurs

Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js”.
client:1
Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/polyfills.515ed9df1f4876ab6cb6.bundle.js”.
client:1
Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/main.f46d9721702aed0cb018.bundle.js”.
client:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `base href` of your `index.html` file from build folder like this -

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

Comment: Glad to know :)